# Allowing admin and users to sign in using same form (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created 2 tables, one for users and one for admins.

I created 2 tables as they both collect different information, but I want to be able to allow a sign in using an email address and password from both the admin and user tables via the same form.

Is this possible? I've looked around and people seem to have created 1 users table and added an admin boolean, but I wanted to avoid this and I didn't want to collect unnecessary data if I didn't need to.

Any help and assistance about how to best go around this would be great.

Comment: Are you using some kind of gem for authentication like `devise`, or are you rolling your own solution?

Comment: I'm trying to learn more on rails, so went for my own solution using a guides and things like railscast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing something from scratch, then it is simply a matter of coding it. I think this approach has some inherent flaws and I would avoid it.

If you want to have some segregation on the model side of things, I suggest you use [STI](https://coderwall.com/p/vgvtlq/users-roles-and-single-table-inheritance-in-rails). That way there is some shared behaviour/attributes and the distinctions can be coded separately, so you have your protection.

If you have plenty of distinct attributes, I would suggest separating them from your user/admin and creating an "admin_profile" model that belongs_to :admin and a "user_profile" that belongs_to :user.

And to make coding "transparent", you can create accessors in your admin model class to get/set the profile attributes seamlessly. Say you have an is_cool attribute on the admin_profile model, but you'd like to access it as

```
imadmin.is_cool
```

You can have in your admin.rb model

```
has_one :admin_profile
def is_cool
  self.admin_profile.is_cool
end
```

be careful cause the has_one relationship may return nil if there is no profile associated with the admin/user.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I'll look into STI and try and get my head around that. :D

Comment: Hi Donato. I've taken a look at this, this morning and was just trying to work out how it would work on the sign up.   I have a user form with 10 fields and admin form with 5 fields.If I was too consildate this into 1 form, how would I manage the form inputs as they only share 4 of the same fields.

Comment: If your application allows for it, you should do a 2-step sign-up. In the first you should collect the info that is strictly necessary for both, say your 4 fields are: email, name, birthdate and password, for example. In the second step you force them to complete the "profile" and each will have a view and add the info to the right model. After the user/admin signs up with the 4 fields, redirect them to the correct page. It's my pleasure to help.

Comment: Excellent, I thought that might be the way to do it. Thanks for the assistance. Always seem to question my own thoughts, so like to get other peoples opinion's and ideas too.